# Can the CV code shown in this video can be used for fixed wing plane?

Tags: unmanned-aerial-vehicle, fixed-wing

https://youtu.be/uzrugbQCO64

This is video mentioned. Its a DIY object tracking uav. Here used is a quadcopter can it be used for fixed wing plane. In this case it is quadcopter. Code only command the ardupilot(arduplane/copter)?

Comment: Recommend you ask on Drone SE.

Comment: Could you clarify what you're asking? None of the aforementioned code is written for a flight controller, so it would only work with the shown Raspberry Pi and not with Ardupilot.

Comment: It's computer vision - what the camera is attached to and how it moves is irrelevant.